# Java toString puts json (gson impl) on logs

Tags: java, json, log4j, gson, tostring

I have multiple classes with toString: some of these have collections.

Is this a good idea to create toString with gson?

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
}
```

I use `toString` for logging with log4j. I don't want exceptions on toString output.
Anyone use this implementation?

*Maybe it's a duplicate question, but I don't find the right answer*

Comment: You will have issues if your objects have back references.

Comment: It's also a lot slower than a "classic" to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson output may be "large" on collections with complex objects.

After evaluate some scenarios, I prefer to use Gson only in **specific points**.

`log.info("[context scenario] Collection<Foo>" + new Gson().toJson(foos))`;

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider Apache Common's [Reflection toString Builder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html). It should be faster than Gson, but still not need to be modified when you add new fields to the model.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
}
```

Comment: Good "toString" alternative, however with Gson we have: deserialization, `new Gson().fromJson(...)` and we are using deserialization for constructing some mocks.